# Can you accept varargs as a value in an annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, variadic-functions

I'd like to create a method annotation that accepts varargs as a default. Here is the use case:

```
@Authorize(Role.PRESIDENT, Role.ARMY_GENERAL, Role.INSANE_MADMAN)
public void secureMethod() {
   // Code to launch nuclear missile (ok, not really)
}
```

This is my annotation interface:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Authorize {

    Role[] value() default {}; // Tempted to say Rights... value() default {}

}
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible, because varargs are valid **only** for constructor/method parameters, not for  members.

And also, even if you could define `value()` with varags, internally the values would be converted to an array anyway, so you wouldn't gain much. Using an array here is just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can just use a literal array

```
@Authorize( {Role.PRESIDENT, Role.ARMY_GENERAL, Role.INSANE_MADMAN } )
public void secureMethod() {

  ...

}
```

An example of this in common use is JUnit's @SuiteClasses which does the same thing

**EDIT**

`@SuppressWarnings` also takes arrays if you have more than one value:

```
 @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
```

Comment: I didn't realise it's that easy to use an array. Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: So the answer is: NO. The accepted answer should be from @Yovkow. I don't understand why so many up votes